# Wordpress website crashes on Windows host

Tags: wordpress, windows, iis, hosting

I have a website: [mywebsite](https://www.pergoflex.ro/) that I created in Wordpress, hosted on a Windows server.
If I try to refresh multiple times I get the following error:

> 500 - Internal server error.
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Restarting application pool in solidCP results the following:

> Page URL:     http://win.hostx.ro/Default.aspx?pid=SpaceWebSites&mid=82&ctl=edit_item&ItemID=32686&SpaceID=1773
> Logged User:    XXX
> Work on Behalf:     XXX
> Hosting Space:  1773
> Stack Trace:    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Error executing 'CHANGE_STATE' task on 'pergoflex.ro' WEB_SITE ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> The service cannot accept control messages at this time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070425)
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.WebServerController.ChangeAppPoolState(Int32 siteItemId, AppPoolState state)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.WebServerController.ChangeAppPoolState(Int32 siteItemId, AppPoolState state)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.esWebServers.ChangeAppPoolState(Int32 siteItemId, AppPoolState state)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
> at SolidCP.EnterpriseServer.esWebServers.ChangeAppPoolState(Int32 siteItemId, AppPoolState state)
> at SolidCP.Portal.WebSitesEditSite.cmdAppPoolChangeState_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

with the 503 error in browser:

> Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: do you have it always and the website is unfunctional. or you encounter 503 only when you reload and hit the wordpress website repeatedly in short intervals of time.

Comment: After multiple refresh i get error 500, to get it working again i need to refresh/restart application pool. On restarting application poll i get the solidcp error and in the browser the 503. (I use TabAutoRefresh in FF with 10 sec refresh time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the application pool where you host your website, Select Advanced settings, set Start Mode to AlwaysRunning.[image]